# How to perform array manipulation

Tags: arrays, yii, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this from cdbcommand select query. (Using Yii)

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 21
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 91
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 125
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 15
                )
        )
)
```

I want final array like `array(21, 91, 125, 15)`

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Flatten a Multidimensional Array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array)

Answer (score 1):

```
$output=array();    
foreach($result as $row){
        foreach($row as $id_container){
            $output[]=$id_container["id"];
        }
    }
```

This will give you what you need, if array structure is dependable - then it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$newArray=array();
foreach($result as $value)
{
array_merge($newArray,array_values($value));
}
```